# Downloading Sentinel-2 data from shapefile of whole country

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2

I have shapefile of a small country: Portugal

I need to download Sentinel-2 data corresponding to the shapefile, or download a bigger one and then cut it.

I tried using SCP plugin of QGIS but only know how to download a small rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do so for free, your best best is to download the relevant gigabyte-sized S2A strip from https://scihub.copernicus.eu/ (possibly using `wget` to do so in the background), and then use GDAL on the command line to cut it with `gdalwarp -cutline`, selecting the bands you need. GDAL can read the compressed downloaded Sentinel 2 file directly without unpacking it first.

This and other operations, for instance calculating NDVI or other indexes using the GDAL raster calcuator `gdal_calc.py` or pansharpening certain bands, can be automated using a script if you process Sentinel 2 data for your ROI frequently.

This is the type of large-scale data wrangling which is best suited to the command line tools in QGIS' ecosystem, like GDAL, rather than using GUI tools or plugins directly.

Comment: thanks for the anwer! will check it out! Do you know of any video or guide that could help?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if you have already looked at this.

[SciHub](https://146.59.215.226/dhus/#/home) has the Sentinel 2 data. You can select a rectangle around Portugal on a map, mission type, sensor, date, etc.

You can then download the resulting tiles. It's likely to be hundreds or even thousands of gigabytes.

Once you know what you want, you can use their API Hub to download programmatically rather than interactively.

As of April 29 2021 they were in the process of changing IP addresses for some of these.

A quick check of data available at SciHub over August 2020 for Sentinel 2 product S2MSI1C over all of Portugal is shown below. Looks like the area is fully covered with less than 15% cloud cover.

[image]

[image]